# Use Javascript/greasemonkey to 'stack' websites

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to type www.aaa.com into url and then have a greasemonkey script that will load www.aaa.com but also load www.bbb.com right below www.aaa.com. You should be able to define the url for www.bbb.com.

my conceptual code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        google-wired
// @namespace   test
// @include     www.google.com
// ==/UserScript==

var secondURL = 'http://www.wired.com';

document.body.appendChild(HTML of second URL)
```

The output would be google's splashpage right on top of wired's splash page.

Comment: Do you want each page to appear in a frame on the same page?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. do you want two frames, with the content separate? Or do you want one site to completely overlay the other one? and if you want it overlaid, do you want the top site to be transparent? Or are you wanting two pages in the same window, where you can switch between them like tabs?

Comment: @MarkHubbart I have posted a question that may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965834/add-a-frame-to-the-bottom-of-a-web-page-using-a-greasemonkey-script

Comment: There's a website called http://www.sitepouch.com that can do this (for some websites), although it's not a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I was hoping to have the pages appear as if the HTML of the second site was concatenated to the HTML of the first. Almost like adding a new div and dropping the second website below the first one. Sitepouch.com does not quite have the effect I am looking for. I want both pages to become one single page so that as I scroll  down, instead of the end of the first page, it just continues as the  top of the second page.

Comment: @user1907403, You can't do this for Google; see [Anderson Green's related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965834/).  If you just append Google's HTML, all the page functionality will be dead, and conflicts with Wired (etc.) are bound to happen.  And, Google won't run in an iframe.  ... However, for sites other than Google, or if just the static HTML is okay, **that** can be done.  Please indicate which case, if any, applies to this question.

Comment: @BrockAdams I guess google was a bad example. I am talking about sites with static HTML.