# Add a frame to the bottom of a web page using a Greasemonkey script (and set its size)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, greasemonkey

Is there any way to add a frame to the bottom of a web page using a Greasemonkey script?

I want to write a script that adds `http://www.google.com` at the bottom of every web page, inside a frame.
I also want the width and height of the frame to be the same as the height of the page that is inside it.

Comment: I found an answer that explains how to add a div at a specified position on a web page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13946081/975097

Comment: Also, this answer explains how to find the height of a web page using JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430070/get-page-height-in-js-cross-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 3 questions in one.

1. Adding an `<iframe>` is easy, by itself:

   ```
   $(document.body).append (
       '<iframe src="http://{SOME_PAGE_BESIDES_GOOGLE!}.com/">'
   );
   ```
2. **But,** Google [will not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808761/331508)   [let you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8524449/331508)   [load it in an `<iframe>`](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/10/23/1949227/google-not-reciprocating-on-iframe-usage) -- blocking that with a variety of tricks, and the *Terms of Service*.
   Plenty of other sites -- including Stack Exchange sites -- also block operation from within an `iframe`.
3. There is a *slight* chance that you could load framed-blocked pages in an `<object>`, **if, and only if, the target page server has [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) set to allow it.**

   It's a safe bet that your target page(s) *don't* have CORS set that way. ;-)   But, if they did, then the code would be like:

   ```
   $(document.body).append ( '                                     \
       <object type="text/html" data="http://www.google.com/">     \
       </object>                                                   \
   ' );
   ```
4. Finally, for those cases when you can actually load an `<iframe>` (or `<object>`), you would need to communicate the page size back up to the container/master/target page, from the loaded iframe.

   To do that, see [*How can two instances of a userscript communicate between frames?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774184/331508).

---

---

For Google on every page, your best bet is to use [the *Google Custom Search API*](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).